# I want to use saga effects in method of class

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, redux-saga

My class looks like this:

```
abstract class Processor {
  canBeRun(action: RootActions, curOrderModal: OrderModalStep, curOrderPage: OrderPageStep): boolean {
    throw new Error('The method must override, canBeRun()');
  }

  *_process(): Generator<any, any, any> {
    throw new Error('The method must override, _process()');
  }
}

class OrignalMembersOrder extends Processor {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  *_process(): Generator<any, any, any> {
    try {
      yield put(setCurOrderPage(OrderPageStep.original));//
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error');
    }
  }
}


export function* test(): Generator<any, any, any> {
  const Array: Processor[] = [];

 Array.push(new OrignalMembersOrder());
 //Array.push(new OtherOrder...()); 
 //Array.push(new OtherOrder...());
 //Array.push(new OtherOrder...());
}

Array.map((processors) => {
    processors._process().next();
  });
```

and call the _process().next() method, I don't get the expected result ...

This part doesn't work

```
*_process(): Generator<any, any, any> {
    try {
      yield console.log("check") // success
      yield put(setCurOrderPage(OrderPageStep.original)); // failure
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error');
    }
  }
```

yield console.log <- success

yield put(setCurOrderPage(OrderPageStep.original)) <- failure

Comment: What's the expected result? What is `Processor`? Where do you call this? Without easily reproducible example you're not likely to get a help..

Comment: okay i edited it.

Comment: Why are you calling `next`? You shouldn't do that (it is done by saga middleware)